# Failing to create associated token account in rust tests. It says insufficient account keys for instruction

Tags: spl-token, testing, solana-program-test, spl-associated-token-account

https://github.com/SushantChandla/test-mint-bug/blob/main/programs/mint-bug/tests/mint.rs

I am trying to create an associated token account please have a look at the github file.
The error I get is `Program ATokenGPvbdGVxr1b2hvZbsiqW5xWH25efTNsLJA8knL failed: insufficient account keys for instruction` which is weird as i am using the function provided in spl-associated-token-account crate and it should create instruction with all the required accounts.

```
async fn create_associated_token_account(
    context: &mut ProgramTestContext,
    account: &Pubkey,
    mint: &Pubkey,
    payer: &Keypair,
) -> transport::Result<Pubkey> {
    let associated_token_account = get_associated_token_address(account, mint);
    let associated_ix = spl_associated_token_account::instruction::create_associated_token_account(
        &payer.pubkey(),
        &account,
        &mint,
    );
    let associated_tx = get_signed_transaction(context, &[associated_ix], payer).await;

    context
        .banks_client
        .process_transaction(associated_tx)
        .await?;

    return Ok(associated_token_account);
}
```

Here are logs:

```
test result: ok. 1 passed; 0 failed; 0 ignored; 0 measured; 0 filtered out; finished in 0.00s

     Running tests/mint.rs (target/debug/deps/mint-b02ef8a2fffb7767)

running 1 test
[2022-08-14T17:00:14.371540000Z INFO  solana_program_test] "mint_bug" BPF program from /Users/sushantchandla/Projects/mint-bug/target/deploy/mint_bug.so, modified 1 minute, 74 ms, 62 µs and 704 ns ago
[2022-08-14T17:00:14.479628000Z DEBUG solana_runtime::message_processor::stable_log] Program 11111111111111111111111111111111 invoke [1]
[2022-08-14T17:00:14.479697000Z TRACE solana_runtime::system_instruction_processor] process_instruction: CreateAccount { lamports: 1461600, space: 82, owner: TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA }
[2022-08-14T17:00:14.479729000Z TRACE solana_runtime::system_instruction_processor] keyed_accounts: [KeyedAccount { is_signer: false, is_writable: false, key: 11111111111111111111111111111111, account: RefCell { value: Account { lamports: 1, data.len: 14, owner: NativeLoader1111111111111111111111111111111, executable: true, rent_epoch: 0, data: 73797374656d5f70726f6772616d } } }, KeyedAccount { is_signer: true, is_writable: true, key: 7seLqAnajhJ5yFDgzFoBEt65ETYfZ99vWiuX3eDzu8Yg, account: RefCell { value: Account { lamports: 99999990000, data.len: 0, owner: 11111111111111111111111111111111, executable: false, rent_epoch: 0 } } }, KeyedAccount { is_signer: true, is_writable: true, key: BgGUR32WU9WJVwxdPKT4cfPnthg53TsikuoMWn8ZzBy8, account: RefCell { value: Account { lamports: 0, data.len: 0, owner: 11111111111111111111111111111111, executable: false, rent_epoch: 0 } } }]
[2022-08-14T17:00:14.479875000Z DEBUG solana_runtime::message_processor::stable_log] Program 11111111111111111111111111111111 success
[2022-08-14T17:00:14.497758000Z DEBUG solana_runtime::message_processor::stable_log] Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA invoke [1]
[2022-08-14T17:00:14.498167000Z DEBUG solana_runtime::message_processor::stable_log] Program log: Instruction: InitializeMint
[2022-08-14T17:00:14.498666000Z DEBUG solana_rbpf::vm] BPF instructions executed (interp): 2253
[2022-08-14T17:00:14.498678000Z DEBUG solana_rbpf::vm] Max frame depth reached: 9
[2022-08-14T17:00:14.498686000Z DEBUG solana_runtime::message_processor::stable_log] Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA consumed 2353 of 200000 compute units
[2022-08-14T17:00:14.498754000Z DEBUG solana_runtime::message_processor::stable_log] Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA success
[2022-08-14T17:00:14.515489000Z DEBUG solana_runtime::message_processor::stable_log] Program ATokenGPvbdGVxr1b2hvZbsiqW5xWH25efTNsLJA8knL invoke [1]
[2022-08-14T17:00:14.516218000Z DEBUG solana_rbpf::vm] BPF instructions executed (interp): 1953
[2022-08-14T17:00:14.516231000Z DEBUG solana_rbpf::vm] Max frame depth reached: 4
[2022-08-14T17:00:14.516239000Z DEBUG solana_runtime::message_processor::stable_log] Program ATokenGPvbdGVxr1b2hvZbsiqW5xWH25efTNsLJA8knL consumed 1953 of 200000 compute units
[2022-08-14T17:00:14.516277000Z DEBUG solana_runtime::message_processor::stable_log] Program ATokenGPvbdGVxr1b2hvZbsiqW5xWH25efTNsLJA8knL failed: insufficient account keys for instruction
test mint_tokens ... FAILED

failures:

---- mint_tokens stdout ----
thread 'mint_tokens' panicked at 'failed to create associated token account: TransactionError(InstructionError(0, NotEnoughAccountKeys))', programs/mint-bug/tests/mint.rs:84:6
note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace


failures:
    mint_tokens

test result: FAILED. 0 passed; 1 failed; 0 ignored; 0 measured; 0 filtered out; finished in 0.15s
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hit the same issue and found there is a difference in behaviour of solana validator versions.
I worked against test validator in version `1.9.29` (developing on localhost). I was using the version of library `spl-associated-token-account` `1.1.1` that based on used import `spl_associated_token_account::instruction` creates the instruction meant for validator in version `1.10` and higher.

In fact, it does not matter of version of difference of `spl-associated-token-account` versions between `1.0.5` and `1.1.1`. The both behaves the same in this regards (while `1.0.3` seems work differently).

See details in discussion here:
https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-program-library/issues/2791

The difference is in account `sysvar::rent::id()` which seems to be required by old solana version (before `1.10`).

If you import
`use spl_associated_token_account::instruction::create_associated_token_account` then you need to work with solana version `1.10` (or higher) as the `sysvar::rent::id()` is not passed in the call. The new version does not require that account to be passed in.
https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-program-library/blob/associated-token-account-v1.1.1/associated-token-account/program/src/instruction.rs#L76

If you import
`use spl_associated_token_account::create_associated_token_account` then you can call against the solana version `1.9` as the `rent::id` is passed in the instruction call.
https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-program-library/blob/associated-token-account-v1.1.1/associated-token-account/program/src/lib.rs#L101

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the `token_program_id`

The `create_associated_token_account` takes four parameters.

```
pub fn create_associated_token_account(
    funding_address: &Pubkey,
    wallet_address: &Pubkey,
    token_mint_address: &Pubkey,
    token_program_id: &Pubkey,
) -> Instruction
```

Comment: indeed, this is true for the latest version 1.1.1 but I am using version 1.0.5 of the crate and the solana version 1.9.29

https://docs.rs/spl-associated-token-account/1.0.5/spl_associated_token_account/instruction/fn.create_associated_token_account.html

Comment: https://docs.rs/spl-associated-token-account/1.0.5/src/spl_associated_token_account/instruction.rs.html#26
The Spl token program id is added already

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. try add system_program_id & spl_token_id account:

```
        invoke(
        &spl_associated_token_account::instruction::create_associated_token_account(
            acc_funder_.key,
            acc_wallet_.key,
            acc_mint_.key,
        ),
        &[
            acc_funder_.clone(),
            acc_wallet_.clone(),
            acc_mint_.clone(),
            tacc_wallet_.clone(),
            acc_system_program_.clone(), // <-
            acc_spl_token_.clone(), // <-
        ]
    )?;
```

because create_associated_token_account wants also 2 implicit parameters

```
pub fn create_associated_token_account(
    funding_address: &Pubkey,
    wallet_address: &Pubkey,
    spl_token_mint_address: &Pubkey,
) -> Instruction {
    let associated_account_address = get_associated_token_address(wallet_address, spl_token_mint_address);

    let instruction_data = AssociatedTokenAccountInstruction::Create {};

Instruction {
    program_id: id(),
    accounts: vec![
        AccountMeta::new(*funding_address, true),
        AccountMeta::new(associated_account_address, false),
        AccountMeta::new_readonly(*wallet_address, false),
        AccountMeta::new_readonly(*spl_token_mint_address, false),
        AccountMeta::new_readonly(solana_program::system_program::id(), false), // <-
        AccountMeta::new_readonly(spl_token::id(), false), // <-
    ],
    data: instruction_data.try_to_vec().unwrap(),
    }
}
```

Comment: maybe you solved it in a different way, if so, write how.