# Creating an Associated Token Account via Solana Program

Tags: associated-token-account, spl-associated-token-account, associated-token-program

I am struggling with creating a program that creates an Associated Token Account (ATA) for a mint I created. I am using the `anchor_spl::associated_token`  for the task. Here is my code:

```
use anchor_lang::prelude::*;

use anchor_spl::token::{Token, Mint};
use anchor_spl::associated_token::{self, AssociatedToken, Create};

declare_id!("Fg6PaFpoGXkYsidMpWTK6W2BeZ7FEfcYkg476zPFsLnS");

#[program]
pub mod token_util {

    use super::*;

    pub fn create_ata(ctx: Context<CreateAta>) -> Result<()> {

        let cpi_accounts = Create {
            payer: ctx.accounts.payer.to_account_info(),
            associated_token: ctx.accounts.token_account.to_account_info(),
            authority: ctx.accounts.payer.to_account_info(),
            mint: ctx.accounts.mint.to_account_info(),
            
            system_program: ctx.accounts.system_program.to_account_info(),
            token_program: ctx.accounts.token_program.to_account_info(),
            rent: ctx.accounts.rent.to_account_info(),
        };

        let cpi_program = ctx.accounts.associated_token_program.to_account_info();

        let cpi_ctx = CpiContext::new(cpi_program, cpi_accounts);
        associated_token::create(cpi_ctx)
    }
}

#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct Purchase<'CreateAta> {

    #[account(mut)]
    pub payer: Signer<'info>,

    /// CHECK: new token account
    #[account(mut)]
    pub token_account: UncheckedAccount<'info>,

    pub mint: Account<'info, Mint>,
    pub token_program: Program<'info, Token>,
    pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,
    pub associated_token_program: Program<'info, AssociatedToken>,
    pub rent: Sysvar<'info, Rent>,
}
```

The PDA I pass via `token_account`  is correctly derived using the seeds that Associated Token Program is expecting:

```
const [pda, bump] = await anchor.web3.PublicKey.findProgramAddress(
      [payer.publicKey.toBytes(), TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID.toBytes(), mint.toBytes()],
      ASSOCIATED_TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID
    );
```

Still, I am getting the following error message when invoking the function `create_ata`:

```
Error: failed to send transaction: Transaction simulation failed: Error processing Instruction 0: insufficient account keys for instruction
```

Could it be, that a signer is missing? Maybe the `token_account` needs to sign the CPI. But I cannot do this via my own program since it is a PDA that needs to be derived from the Associated Token Program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem: I was using an older Solana-CLI version that did not support the newer instructions of spl_associated_token_account that anchor_spl is using. Upgrading my Solana-CLI from 1.9.29 to 1.11.10 did the trick. Here is a more detailed explanation of the issue: solana.stackexchange.com/a/2873/1138

Answer (score 7):

try using the `init_if_needed` constraint
here's a Solpg reference you can test: https://beta.solpg.io/631a439777ea7f12846aee89

```
#[program]
mod example {
    use super::*;
    pub fn initialize(ctx: Context<Initialize>) -> Result<()> {
        Ok(())
    }
}

#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct Initialize<'info> {
    #[account(
        init_if_needed,
        payer = payer, 
        associated_token::mint = mint, 
        associated_token::authority = payer
    )]
    pub token_account: Account<'info, TokenAccount>,
    pub mint: Account<'info, Mint>,
     #[account(mut)]
    pub payer: Signer<'info>,
    pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,
    pub token_program: Program<'info, Token>,
    pub associated_token_program: Program<'info, AssociatedToken>,
    pub rent: Sysvar<'info, Rent>,
}
```

You'll also need to update `Cargo.toml` in your project to use `init_if_needed`

```
[dependencies]
anchor-lang = { version = "0.25.0", features = ["init-if-needed"] }
```

You can get the associated token account address using `getAssociatedTokenAddress`

```
import { getAssociatedTokenAddress } from "@solana/spl-token"

const tokenAddress = await getAssociatedTokenAddress(
   mint,
   user.publicKey
)
```

You can then call the function in your Anchor tests file like this

```
import * as anchor from "@project-serum/anchor"
import { Program } from "@project-serum/anchor"
import {
  getAssociatedTokenAddress,
  createMint,
  TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
  ASSOCIATED_TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
  getAccount,
} from "@solana/spl-token"
import { Example } from "../target/types/example"

describe("Example", () => {
  anchor.setProvider(anchor.AnchorProvider.env())

  const program = anchor.workspace.Example as Program<Example>
  const connection = anchor.getProvider().connection
  const userWallet = anchor.workspace.Example.provider.wallet

  it("Test Instruction", async () => {
    const mint = await createMint(
      connection,
      userWallet.payer,
      userWallet.publicKey,
      userWallet.publicKey,
      6
    )

    const tokenAccountAddress = await getAssociatedTokenAddress(
      mint,
      userWallet.publicKey
    )

    await program.methods
      .initialize()
      .accounts({
        payer: userWallet.publicKey,
        tokenAccount: tokenAccountAddress,
        mint: mint,
        tokenProgram: TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
        associatedTokenProgram: ASSOCIATED_TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
        systemProgram: anchor.web3.SystemProgram.programId,
        rent: anchor.web3.SYSVAR_RENT_PUBKEY,
      })
      .rpc()

    const account = await getAccount(connection, tokenAccountAddress)
    console.log(account)
  })
})
```

Anchor can infer some of the accounts, so you can also shorten to this

```
await program.methods
  .initialize()
  .accounts({
    tokenAccount: tokenAccountAddress,
    mint: mint,
  })
  .rpc()
```

You can run `anchor expand` to see all the code that Anchor generates for you. Below is the code snippet that relates to `init_if_needed`

```
let token_account: anchor_lang::accounts::account::Account<TokenAccount> = {
    if !true
    || AsRef::<AccountInfo>::as_ref(&token_account).owner
    == &anchor_lang::solana_program::system_program::ID
    {
      let payer = payer.to_account_info();
      let cpi_program = associated_token_program.to_account_info();
      let cpi_accounts = anchor_spl::associated_token::Create {
        payer: payer.to_account_info(),
        associated_token: token_account.to_account_info(),
        authority: payer.to_account_info(),
        mint: mint.to_account_info(),
        system_program: system_program.to_account_info(),
        token_program: token_program.to_account_info(),
        rent: rent.to_account_info(),
      };
      let cpi_ctx = anchor_lang::context::CpiContext::new(
        cpi_program,
        cpi_accounts,
      );
      anchor_spl::associated_token::create(cpi_ctx)?;
    }
  ...
}
```

Comment: Still getting the same error: `insufficient account keys for instruction`.

Comment: Can you share any updates you've made to the instruction and how you're building the transaction? Also, you can get the ATA using `getAssociatedTokenAddress` from `@solana/web3.js`

Comment: this is how I am calling the function:
https://beta.solpg.io/631ae83477ea7f12846aee8b

Comment: I tried to call the instruction the way you set it up and it seems to work, copy pasted into the post. Maybe double check the way you set up `provider.wallet.publicKey`?

Comment: what network are you using? I tried to submit the transaction in an Anchor test, submitting to the default local network that is started when you execute a test suite on Anchor. I also tried with a local network that I manually started via `solana-test-validator` and then started the test with the `--skip-local-validator`.

Comment: I found the problem: I was using an older Solana-CLI version that did not support the newer instructions of `spl_associated_token_account` that `anchor_spl` is using. Upgrading my Solana-CLI from `1.9.29`  to `1.11.10` did the trick. Here is a more detailed explanation of the issue: https://solana.stackexchange.com/a/2873/1138

Comment: Nonetheless, I am very curious about your approach using `init_if_needed`. I wonder how it correctly calculates the PDA. How does it know the order of the seeds?

Comment: you can run `anchor expand` to see all the code that Anchor generates for you

Comment: my configuration is totally same, the only difference is I am using Token2022, with program id TOKEN_2022_PROGRAM_ID still getting `Error: failed to send transaction: Transaction simulation failed: Error processing Instruction 0: An account required by the instruction is missing` any idea why this is happening?