# How to create Associated token Account onchain

Tags: anchor, solana-program, anchor-lang, spl-associated-token-account, anchor-spl

Please help i'm trying to create an Associated token account for a PDA onchain using

```
        let create_accounts = Create {
            payer: ctx.accounts.signer.to_account_info().clone(),
            associated_token: ctx.accounts.token_escrow.to_account_info().clone(),
            authority: ctx.accounts.another_pda.to_account_info().clone(),
            mint: ctx.accounts.token_mint.to_account_info().clone(),
            system_program: ctx.accounts.system_program.to_account_info().clone(),
            token_program: ctx.accounts.token_program.to_account_info().clone(),
            rent: ctx.accounts.rent.to_account_info().clone(),
        };

        let cpi_ctx = CpiContext::new(
            self.associated_token_program.to_account_info().clone(),
            create_accounts,
        );

        anchor_spl::associated_token::create(cpi_ctx)?;
```

But I'm getting this error

```
Error: failed to send transaction: Transaction simulation failed: Error processing Instruction 0: An account required by the instruction is missing
```

Comment: Could be this related with issue of the spl sdk and solana version mismatch (version higher to 1.0.5 needs Solana blockchain in version 1.10? See https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/2034/failing-to-create-associated-token-account-in-rust-tests-it-says-insufficient-a/2873#2873

Comment: thanks @chalda i've gotten the issue... i was mixing up the associated token seeds

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it turns out i was generating the Associated token account using the wrong seeds.

Here's the proper way to go about it

```
import {
  TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
} from "@solana/spl-token";

const SPL_ASSOCIATED_TOKEN_ACCOUNT_PROGRAM_ID: PublicKey = new PublicKey(
  'ATokenGPvbdGVxr1b2hvZbsiqW5xWH25efTNsLJA8knL',
);

export async function findAssociatedTokenAddress(
  ownerAddress: PublicKey,
  tokenMintAddress: PublicKey,
  programId: PublicKey = SPL_ASSOCIATED_TOKEN_ACCOUNT_PROGRAM_ID
): Promise<PublicKey> {
  return (await PublicKey.findProgramAddress(
    [
      ownerAddress.toBuffer(),
      TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID.toBuffer(),
      tokenMintAddress.toBuffer(),
    ],
    programId
  ))[0];
}
```

Comment: Ok but this answer is not the "onchain" answer. It's a client example of finding the PDA

Comment: yeah... the answer is already in the question @HenryE

Comment: The issue is if someone searches for how to create an onchain associated token account, this will not be the correct answer for them. The answer goes in the answer, the question in the question